# site map path take specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I had a problem in site map path 
I had navigation bar which take from sit map path 
but I want site map path tack value from page as product 
also how can i remove underline in site map path

this my site map path:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="True"
    ForeColor="White">
    <PathSeparatorStyle ForeColor="White" />
    <NodeStyle ForeColor="White" />
    <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="White" />
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Comment: Do you have a working sample you can link here? I think people are going to have trouble understanding what you are after...

Comment: as
Home  >Notebook Computers >Satellite

Comment: look notebook is product no page

Comment: if you select specific value appear on navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sitemappath to take the page's value just include it in you sitemap. But if you wish it to take a dynamic value then ı suppose you need to write your own sitemapprovider. Indeed nowadays I am trying to find a similar solution...

And to prevent underlining create a Css property for node style and within the definition of that css class set text-decoration: none;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

and add this style to your node :

```
<NodeStyle CssClass="style1" Font-Bold="True"/>
```